# Unable to swap deployment slots

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, azure-deployment-slots

I have an Azure function with production and staging deployment slots. I see the swap failing due to the following error:

Cannot swap site slots for site because the 'staging' slot did not respond to http ping. (CODE: 417)

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: do you have WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = on?

Comment: Turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs, also can you post how are you deploying? manual or azure devops?

Comment: Yes I have this setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = on

Comment: Could you try by stopping the staging slot and starting after 20 to 30 seconds and then check!

Comment: Check this GitHub [issue 60410](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/60410) and do let me know if it helps

Comment: @user989988 Were you able to find a solution to this problem?  There is a similar issue reported in GItHub here (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8969).

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot swap site slots for site because the 'Staging' slot did not respond to http ping

This issue is registered twice in the two different GitHub Repositories with years gap.

The 1st registered issue [60410](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/60410) is the not on Azure Functions specifically but with the same error and @*BryanTranch-MSFT* stated that the deployment or swapping failure occurs in an Azure App Service due to if no limit defined on local cache.

Thanks to @*user527614* for bringing the recent registered issue on Azure Functions Host - Slot Swap Failing with `Http Ping` to the current page.

User @*fabiocav* mentioned that the patch is deployed for resolving this issue in different regions and the information is given in the GitHub Issue No [8969](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8969).

The issue is still in Open state, impacted many Azure users and affected in many regions and also please mention your scenario details if any different in process with the same error in the same GitHub issue page.

If any possible solution or fix comes, I will update the answer here accordingly that would help all the community members who are facing a similar issue.